# Aiogram как при нажатии на inline кнопку автоматически заполнить поле для ввода текста?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, aiogram, telethon

Всем здравствуйте! Есть ли в aiogram метод, который позволил бы заполнить по согласию пользователя строку для ввода текста? И если нет, то есть ли для тг ботов в принципе такая возможность? (Telethon и т.п тоже подойдут). Данная функция нужна чисто для админки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Такого нету....